# Limit doesn't turn out as expected

Tags: limits, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to find the limit of the following function at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and as $n$ approaches infinity:
$$\frac{\ln(\tan x)-\tan^{n}x\lfloor\sin(\tan\frac{x}{2})\rfloor}{1+\tan^{n}x}.$$

The left-hand limit is $\ln(\tan x)$ as expected, but apparently the right-hand limit is $-\lfloor\sin(\tan\frac{x}{2})\rfloor$.

Now, since the $\tan^{n}x$ in the numerator, which approaches infinity, is multiplied with $0$ (since $\sin(\tan\frac{x}{2}$) lies between $0$ and $1$, and the floor function turns it to $0$), shouldn't it end up as $0$? And while the log value is a small positive value, the denominator approaches infinity, so shouldn't the final right hand limit come out as zero?

What's the error I'm making here?

Comment: Oh, sorry, apparently they're both the same! When you evaluate the expression with the floor function with x =$\frac{π}{4}$, it ends up as zero! Is this right? Should I delete this?

Answer (score 1):

On the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)$, we find that $\lfloor \sin(\tan(x/2))\rfloor=0$, so on that interval we have that

$$ \frac{\ln(\tan x)-\tan^{n}x\lfloor\sin(\tan\frac{x}{2})\rfloor}{1+\tan^{n}x}=\frac{\ln(\tan x)}{1+\tan^nx} $$

But this function is continuous on that interval, for any integer $n$ and equals $0$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

So

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{\ln(\tan x)-\tan^{n}x\lfloor\sin(\tan\frac{x}{2})\rfloor}{1+\tan^{n}x}=0 $$

Comment: Isn't the interval $(0, \frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: If you are taking a limit as $x$ approaches $\pi/4$ from the left, then you only need to consider an interval to the left of $\pi/4$, but the undirected limit is $0$ regardless.

Comment: Yes, so shouldn't the interval be $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ and not $(\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{3\pi}{8})$?

Comment: There is no 'the interval'. The point is that there exista 'an interval' containing $\pi/4$ over which the function simplifies, and the limit of the simplified function is $0$ at $\pi/4$. The interval $(0,\pi/4)$ is not relevant to the issue.